# How to better expose a question

Tags: discussion, questions

A kind person answered my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910771/why-does-microsoft-azure-or-swift-in-general-fail-to-update-a-variable-to-retu) (my first ever on SO) within the hour.

I, having only 8 points of reputation, could not give his answer an upvote.
All I could do was approve his answer and comment "thanks".

Not only is his answer superb, it clearly shows that some people on SO answer for the sake of others, not necessarily for points.

Nevertheless, I would like other people to see the question and upvote his answer.

For future reference, is there any way to maximize a question's exposure?

Comment: I expect the meta effect to kick in shortly.

Comment: Join Twitter, get millions of followers, then tweet to them to reward the user with many upvotes and bounties.

Comment: @Will Second step is unlikely ;)

Answer (score 7):

There's really not much you can do with less than 15 reputation except share a link to it...but the next privilege, which allows you to vote a question up [is *at* 15 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).  Nominally you would use that to express your gratitude for an answer.

From where you're at now, that's two upvotes on a question or an upvote on an answer to attain.

Maximizing a question's exposure is a much harder target to hit, since "maximize" means different things to different people.  Bounties are the most common way to do it, but they require 75 reputation and take a minimum of 50 reputation away from you.

As mentioned earlier, using the "share" link would be a good way to get others to look at the question; just be careful that you don't go around spamming it on every website with a form that you see.